# Directions in Google Maps stopped working, when I added geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, directions

I'm trying to make Google Maps directions work with geolocation (using samples provided by Google Maps). Alone both work, but when combined there is a problem, that the map won't show the path (however autocomplete works fine).

```
     function initMap() {
if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude},
          zoom: 10
        });
  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude},
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      });
      var usermarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude},
    draggable: true,
  map: map,
  icon: 'http://x3.cdn03.imgwykop.pl/c3201142/comment_aBtolaUIxKS7cvUnii43PWDPT3Lqduc2,w400.jpg',
});
// test marker
     var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat:50.671064, lng:17.926138},
    draggable: true,
  map: map,
  icon: 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/1e/4d/1e4d8093e7011575d9266598a06d8ecb.png',
});
 });
        new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
      }
 /**
        * @constructor
       */
      function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.originPlaceId = null;
        this.destinationPlaceId = null;
        this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
        var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
        var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
        var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
        var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
      }
     //everything works until this moment
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        var me = this;
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          me.travelMode = mode;
          me.route();
        });
      };
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
        var me = this;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.place_id) {
            window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
            return;
          }
          if (mode === 'ORIG') {
            me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
          } else {
            me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
          }
          me.route();
        });
      };
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
        if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
          return;
        }
        var me = this;

        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
          destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
          travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
         //   map.setStreetView(panorama);
        });
      };
}
```

Comment: any information in the console?

Comment: Yes. Event tracked Multipane Show Live Preview Paneselector undefined undefined    InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map

Comment: any indication from the stack trace where in your code this error may be originating

Comment: well, `var map` is declared inside the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback ... but you do `new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);` outside of it ... so `map` is undefined ... explains the **not an instance of Map** part of the error

Comment: So how can I change that? When I'm trying to simply copy-paste the 'new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);' part inside 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition'  i get errors.

Comment: `I get errors` ... you get errors anyway. What errors do you get if you put that code where it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with putting the path making part in various positions and finaly got it working. @Jaromanda X - thanks for the idea :)

```
 function initMap() {


if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude},
          zoom: 10
        });

     var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat:50.671064, lng:17.926138},
    draggable: true,
  map: map,
  icon: 'http://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/cache/1e/4d/1e4d8093e7011575d9266598a06d8ecb.png',
});

var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude},
        pov: {
          heading: 34,
          pitch: 10
        }
      });
      var usermarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude},
    draggable: true,
  map: map,
  icon: 'http://x3.cdn03.imgwykop.pl/c3201142/comment_aBtolaUIxKS7cvUnii43PWDPT3Lqduc2,w400.jpg',
});
  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
      });
 /**
        * @constructor
       */
      function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
        this.map = map;
        this.originPlaceId = null;
        this.destinationPlaceId = null;
        this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
        var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
        var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
        var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');
        this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            originInput, {placeIdOnly: true});
        var destinationAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            destinationInput, {placeIdOnly: true});

        this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
        this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
        this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(destinationInput);
        this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
      }


      // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
      // Autocomplete.
      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(id, mode) {
        var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
        var me = this;
        radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          me.travelMode = mode;
          me.route();
        });
      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(autocomplete, mode) {
        var me = this;
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.place_id) {
            window.alert("Please select an option from the dropdown list.");
            return;
          }
          if (mode === 'ORIG') {
            me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
          } else {
            me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
          }
          me.route();
        });

      };

      AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
        if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
          return;
        }
        var me = this;

        this.directionsService.route({
          origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
          destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
          travelMode: this.travelMode
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }


            map.setStreetView(panorama);

        });

      };
}
}
```